# Can't install neovim v0.8.0+ on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, kde, apt, neovim

I can't intstall `neovim 0.8.0+` on `KDE neon` (based on `ubuntu`). I need `neovim 0.8+` for [LunarVim](https://www.lunarvim.org/docs/installation). `apt` says the next:

```
➜  ~ LV_BRANCH='release-1.2/neovim-0.8' bash <(curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lunarvim/lunarvim/master/utils/installer/install.sh)

      88\                                                   88\
      88 |                                                  \__|
      88 |88\   88\ 888888$\   888888\   888888\ 88\    88\ 88\ 888888\8888\
      88 |88 |  88 |88  __88\  \____88\ 88  __88\\88\  88  |88 |88  _88  _88\
      88 |88 |  88 |88 |  88 | 888888$ |88 |  \__|\88\88  / 88 |88 / 88 / 88 |
      88 |88 |  88 |88 |  88 |88  __88 |88 |       \88$  /  88 |88 | 88 | 88 |
      88 |\888888  |88 |  88 |\888888$ |88 |        \$  /   88 |88 | 88 | 88 |
      \__| \______/ \__|  \__| \_______|\__|         \_/    \__|\__| \__| \__|

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Detecting platform for managing any additional neovim dependencies
[ERROR]: LunarVim requires at least Neovim v0.8 or higher
➜  ~ sudo apt install neovim  
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
neovim is already the newest version (0.6.1-3).
Starting pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 0
Starting 2 pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 0
Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
➜  ~ LV_BRANCH='release-1.2/neovim-0.8' bash <(curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lunarvim/lunarvim/master/utils/installer/install.sh)

      88\                                                   88\
      88 |                                                  \__|
      88 |88\   88\ 888888$\   888888\   888888\ 88\    88\ 88\ 888888\8888\
      88 |88 |  88 |88  __88\  \____88\ 88  __88\\88\  88  |88 |88  _88  _88\
      88 |88 |  88 |88 |  88 | 888888$ |88 |  \__|\88\88  / 88 |88 / 88 / 88 |
      88 |88 |  88 |88 |  88 |88  __88 |88 |       \88$  /  88 |88 | 88 | 88 |
      88 |\888888  |88 |  88 |\888888$ |88 |        \$  /   88 |88 | 88 | 88 |
      \__| \______/ \__|  \__| \_______|\__|         \_/    \__|\__| \__| \__|

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Detecting platform for managing any additional neovim dependencies
[ERROR]: LunarVim requires at least Neovim v0.8 or higher
➜  ~
```

[Actual screenshot of terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AAV0P.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This tells us what LunarVim says. What happens when you try to install NeoVim? This is what we need to know in order to figure this out for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by building `neovim v0.8.0+` from source.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 3):

Here are some alternative options:

- Install `neovim` via `guix package --install neovim`: https://packages.guix.gnu.org/packages/neovim (has 0.9.1 at the time or writing this).
  Install *`guix`* in turn with `apt install guix`
- Install `neovim` via `nix-env --install neovim`.
  Install *`nix-env`* with `apt install nix-bin`:
  https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/nix-bin
- Install `neovim` from the *`makedeb` Package Repository*: https://mpr.makedeb.org/packages/neovim

Currently, Ubuntu is still stuck at `neovim` 0.7.2: https://packages.ubuntu.com/mantic/neovim

Comment: In case you struggle to set up makedeb (like I did), the instructions you need are at https://docs.makedeb.org/prebuilt-mpr/getting-started/#setting-up-the-repository After that, just do `sudo apt install neovim` and you're golden.

Answer (score 0):

make 1 - `nvim --version`
2 try remove current nvim (example now 0.6.4.) `sudo apt remove neovim`
3 and again install neovim for example [enter link description here](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/releases)
if you use Ubuntu

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).